# does equality operator return a boolean value

Tags: java, equality, operator-keyword

even = number % 2 == 0;

This is a valid java assignment which was given in a website as example.

So does equality operator return a boolean value after evaluation ?

Like in this case, number % 2 == 0 , if true, it assigns even = true?

Comment: Ask yourself: Would anything else make any sense?

Comment: @delnan: Perhaps not, but there are plenty of languages (C, C++) in which the equality operator yields an integer.

Comment: @Keith: That's because those languages don't have dedicated booleans (and use the integers 0 and 1 in their place, or more generally zero and non-zero numbers). And for that matter, at least some of those languages guaranteed that comparisions yield a 0 or 1. And then there's the issue that Java isn't one of those languages...

Comment: @delnan: More or less.  Both C (the 1999 standard) and C++ have dedicated boolean types, but they're derived from languages that didn't.  The point is you can't determine whehter "==" yields a boolean by thinking about whether it makes sense; you need to see what the language standard actually says.

Comment: Thank you all... :)
I had not come across this kind of a statement where equality operator is tested and the boolean value assigned - all one line. So got little confused. 
All answers were useful and have got clarity.
Thanks so much once again.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Comparison operators evaluate to `boolean` values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From the Java Language Specification, [section 15.21](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21):

> The equality operators are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right), but this fact is essentially never useful; for example, a==b==c parses as (a==b)==c. **The result type of `a==b` is always `boolean`**, and c must therefore be of type boolean or a compile-time error occurs. Thus, a==b==c does not test to see whether a, b, and c are all equal.

(Emphasis mine - the rest of the paragraph is *somewhat* irrelevant, but it's the context in which the important phrase appears.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, comparisons made with [boolean operators](http://www.sap-img.com/java/java-boolean-logical-operators.htm) evaluate to a `boolean` value